# SMTP Error 5.7.1 when sending external mail to sharepoint

Tags: windows-server-2003, sharepoint, smtp, exchange-2003

I have SharePoint setup to receive mail from exchange 2003 and all works great internally. However when I send a mail from a external source it fails with a 5.7.1 error. I have setup a SMTP connector in exchange for the name space and allowed relays.

Any comments welcome

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full content of the error message you received ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this working thanks anyway.

Problem was that the contact that sharepoint creates had the tick box for allow authenticated users only ticked in the message restrictions tab.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the answer, so everyone benefits.

Answer (score 0):

`5.7.1` means Relaying Prohibited, basically the only machine allowed to send mail to recipients of your Exchange 2003 server, is itself.